# Using Find and Replace Tool (fnr.exe) with --excludeFileMask

Tags: regex, windows, replace, find

I have to replace a certain string inside strings (any occurrence within apostrophes) in a hole project. The tool I am using is the "Find And Replace Tool" (fnr.exe, https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/). I am using Microsoft Windows.

The strings to be replaced are in .cls files (Smalltalk) in C:\MyDirectory. But there are some folders which contain files that should be excluded from the replacement (NoSearch). Therefore I am using the following command:

```
fnr.exe --cl --dir "C:\MyDirectory" --fileMask "*.cls" --excludeFileMask ".\NoSearch\*" --includeSubDirectories --useRegEx --showEncoding --find "(?<='.*)MyString(?=.*')"
```

(Only finding at the moment, to verify that matching works correct; I replaced the real paths with surrogates)

But the command also matches files in "C:\MyDirectory\NoSearch". So I tried the following values for excludeFileMask, too:

- `.\NoSearch\*.*`
- `.*\\NoSearch\\.*`
- `*NoSearch*`

None of this works. I must be basically missing how the excludeFileMask-Command works. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

It seems that the mask can only be used for file names themselves, without any directory. Fortunately, all files I wanted to exclude had certain prefixes to identify them. Using them with wildcards works. For example `NoSearchPrefix_*.*` excludes all files which start with "NoSearchPrefix_".

Comment: Thanks for editing. This looks much better.